# calculating a marginal effect for logit model

Tags: econometrics, regression, statistics, self-study, logit

For the logit estimate of the slope parameter,I would like to obtain the marginal effect of the regressor ndisease evaluated at $\Lambda (x'\beta)=\bar{y}$, where $\bar{y}$ is mean of $y$.

I obtain the logic estimation as follows:

[image]

How can I calculate this marginal effect by using Stata?

Answer (score 1):

For marginal effects you can use `margins`. This is postestimation command so it should be run after you estimate your regression.

You seem to be running:

`logit DMED NDISEASE`

afterwards you can run:

`margins, predict(p outcome(1)) varlist(NDISEASE)`

I am sure `margins` will give you the marginal effects, the other commands after comma might need adjusting depending on your specific problem, since you dont provide minimal working example thats the most I can do. You can have look at manual for [margins](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rmargins.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. I know the command "marigins" gives the marginal effect. But, the question asks for a specific type of marginal effect. I guess, the question asks the marginal effect at the $x_i$ that coincides with the average observation value of $y$. I would like to learn how can I do this specific one.

Comment: @1190 that’s what the commands after margins should do